# Decomposition of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, continuity

I've been playing with this a bit and not making much progress.  If I have a increasing, continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(1/2)=0$, is it always possible to find some function $\hat{f}$ such that:

$$f(x)= \hat{f}(x)-\hat{f}(1-x)$$

If such a decomposition exists, is it unique (up to constant addition)?

One such thought is if I can do this for any polynomial can I use Stone-Weierstrass to extend it to all continuous functions?

Comment: Must $f(\frac{1}{2})$ be equal to 0?

Comment: Apologies, yes I should have added that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the variable so $t=x-\frac{1}{2}$ then
Rewrite $f(x) = \hat{f}(x)-\hat{f}(1-x)$ into
$$f(t+\frac{1}{2}) = \hat{f}(t+\frac{1}{2})-\hat{f}(\frac{1}{2}-t), $$ 
Let $y(t)=f(t+\frac{1}{2})$ and $\hat{y}(t)=\hat{f}(t+\frac{1}{2})$, so that $\hat{f}(\frac{1}{2}-t)=\hat{y}(-t)$
Let $\hat{y}(t)=g(t)+h(t)$ such, that $g(t)=g(-t), h(t)=-h(-t)$. It's possible indeed while we take $g(t)=\frac{\hat{y}(t)+\hat{y}(-t)}{2}$ and $h(t)=\frac{\hat{y}(t)-\hat{y}(-t)}{2}$.
So $y(t)=\hat{y}(t)+\hat{y}(-t)=g(t)+h(t)+g(-t)+h(-t)=2g(t)$. So we let $g(t)=\frac{y(t)}{2}$ and reverse the process.

> If such a decomposition exists, is it unique (up to constant addition)?

Not unique since we may take arbitrary $h(t)$ satisfying $h(t)=-h(-t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. If such $\hat f$ exists, it implies that $f(\frac12)=\hat f(\frac12)-\hat f(1-\frac12)=0$.

Comment: You're wholly correct, I've edited the question to reflect that that must be true (gotten rid of positivity and instead said that $f(1/2)=0$).  This is simply a made up problem rather than one of direct application so the initial statement of it needed rethinking.  Yours is obviously a good observation though.